# how to have a list of dictionaries in Objective C?

Tags: python, objective-c, list, nsdictionary

here is a an example in python

```
    temy_dict_list = []
my_dict_list.append({'text':'first value', 'value':'number 1'})
my_dict_list.append({'text':'second value', 'value':'number 2'})
my_dict_list.append({'text':'third value', 'value':'number 3'})
```

I want to implement something the same as this in objective-c !

how can i implement this ? i want a list of dictionaries!

Comment: Can you explain what that Python code does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* list = [NSMutableArray array];
[list addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"first value",@"text", @"number 1",@"value", nil]];
[list addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"second value",@"text", @"number 2",@"value", nil]];
[list addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"third value",@"text", @"number 3",@"value", nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1,dict2,nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know python (and your code seems wrong to me), but I guess you want to have an array of dictionaries, which is translated to having an `NSArray` (`NSMutableArray` in this case) which holds one ore more `NSDictionary` objects.

You can create an `NSMutableArray` instance and add add to it some objects.

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[anArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys: @"first-value", @"text", @"number-1", @"value", nil]];
[anArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys: @"second-value", @"text", @"number-2", @"value", nil]];
[anArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys: @"third-value", @"text", @"number-3", @"value", nil]];
// ...
// don't forget to release anArray
[anArray release];
```

We create an `NSDictionary` with the class method `dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys`; we pass a nil-terminated list of values and keys that the dictionary will hold.